# ¿Como modificar un array mulltidimensional de objetos y convertirlo solo en un array de objetos Laravel / PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, array, objeto

Hola a todos esta vez acudo a ustedes por este problema que me he encontrado y no he podido resolver tengo el siguiente código, el cual genera consultas a diversas tablas en mi base datos los nombres de las tablas las almaceno en una variable para luego con un ciclo forEach generar los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function getCustomData($id)
    {
        try {
            $tables = CatAdministrator::where('cat_modules_id', $id)->pluck('table_name');
            // Tables contiene ['tabla1','tabla2'];
            $data = null;
            foreach($tables as $table) {             
                $data .= DB::table($table)->get();
            }
     
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $data
            ]);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que esto me genera la siguiente estructura en $data

```
$data = [
          {"id":1,"genero":"Masculino"},
          {"id":2,"genero":"Femenino"},
          {"id":3,"genero":"Indefinido"}
        ][
           {"id":1,"puestos":"Desarrollador Full Stack Developer"}
         ];
```

¿Como puedo quitar los corchetes de la segunda tabla para que me quede una estructura como lasiguiente?

```
$data = [
           {"id":1,"genero":"Masculino"},
           {"id":2,"genero":"Femenino"},
           {"id":3,"genero":"Indefinido"},
           {"id":1,"puestos":"Desarrollador Full Stack Developer"}
         ];
```

De ante mano les agradezco sus respuestas y comentarios igual si alguien conoce alguna forma mejor que la mía de hacer consultas a varias tablas a partir de un array con la QueryBuilder de Laravel y que retorne una mejor estructura de los datos estoy abierto a recibir opiniones, sin más les agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: Hola, me sorprende que puedas concatenar arrays como lo hace tu código (con un punto). Para lograr lo que necesitas debes usar [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php). Dentro del foreach podrías hacer algo como `$data = array_merge($data, DB::table($table)->get());` , pero antes debes inicializar el `$data = [];`  arriba del foreach. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Me maro este error {"success":false,"message":"array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given"}

Comment: Necesitas forzosamente que los elementos sean objetos? Podrías convertir todo a arrays y utilizar array_merge como dijo @jsan5709

DB::table($table)->get()->toArray()

Comment: No necesariamente tiene que ser un objeto @HeytalePazguato el problema es que ya probe el código que me proponen y me marca el siguiente error message":"array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given"}, gracias por sus ayudas.

Comment: Exactamente por eso te comenté que puedes agregar ->toArray() en el query. El error te aparece porque DB::table($table)->get() devuelve un objeto pero si pones DB::table($table)->get()->toArray() debería funcionar

Comment: Probe lo que me haz indicado @HeytalePazguato y funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias, puedes responder la pregunta si gustas para aceptar la respuesta como valida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar array_merge para crear un solo arreglo

Ten en cuenta que array_merge utiliza como parámetros arreglos, por lo que debes convertir la consulta a tu base de datos a arreglo, si agregas toArray() a la consulta debería funcionar

```
$data = array_merge($data, DB::table($table)->get()->toArray())
```